True Inference with Layoutlmv3
I fine-tuned LayoutLMv3 for token classification to extract key entities. I prepared a dataset using LabelStudio to train and test, and it worked well. However, I want to know how I can get a true inference with a new image
Reference: https://medium.com/@shivarama/layoutlmv3-from-zero-to-hero-part-3-16ae58291e9d

To start, we need to determine what the model should predict, which in this case are the ner_tags. The inputs will be the image, normalized bounding boxes (bboxes), and text extracted via OCR.
First, define your image and collect its dimensions:
img_file = '/content/images/my_image.png'
image = Image.open(img_file)
width, height = image.size

Next, perform OCR. Here, I'll use EasyOCR:
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['pt'])
detections = reader.readtext(img_file)

EasyOCR returns a data structure with the boxes and text, but we need to format the boxes to the model's expected format (x1, y1, x2, y2). Also, let's define functions to scale and then descale the bounding boxes:
from typing import List

def scale_bounding_box(box: List[int], width: int, height: int) -> List[int]:
    return [
        int(box[0] * (1000 / width)),
        int(box[1] * (1000 / height)),
        int(box[2] * (1000 / width)),
        int(box[3] * (1000 / height))
    ]

def unnormalize_box(box: List[int], width: int, height: int) -> List[int]:
    return [
        width * (box[0] / 1000),
        height * (box[1] / 1000),
        width * (box[2] / 1000),
        height * (box[3] / 1000),
    ]

test_dict = {'tokens': [], 'bboxes': []}
test_dict['img_path'] = image

for detection in detections:
    points, text, confidence = detection
    new_left = min(point[0] for point in points)
    new_upper = min(point[1] for point in points)
    new_right = max(point[0] for point in points)
    new_lower = max(point[1] for point in points)

    box = [int(new_left), int(new_upper), int(new_right), int(new_lower)]
    test_dict['tokens'].append(text)

Now, we have a dictionary with the image, the words (tokens), and the scaled boxes. Next, perform the inference.
Define the processor and load the model:
from transformers import AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoProcessor
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("/content/model/checkpoint-200")
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/layoutlmv3-large", apply_ocr=False)

Encode the features as you did during training, without passing the ner_tags (since you don’t have them):
encoding = processor(test_dict['img_path'].convert('RGB'),
                     test_dict['tokens'],
                     boxes=test_dict['bboxes'],
                     max_length=512, 
                     padding="max_length",
                     truncation=True, 
                     return_tensors="pt")

Proceed to inference:
import torch

with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**encoding)

logits = outputs.logits
probabilities = torch.softmax(logits, dim=-1)
predictions = logits.argmax(-1).squeeze().tolist()
token_boxes = encoding.bbox.squeeze().tolist()
confidence_scores = probabilities.max(-1).values.squeeze().tolist()

if len(token_boxes) == 512:
    predictions = [predictions]
    token_boxes = [token_boxes]
    confidence_scores = [confidence_scores]

Finally, display the results:
for i in range(len(token_boxes)):
    for j in range(len(token_boxes[i])):
        label = id2label[predictions[i][j]]
        text = processor.tokenizer.decode(encoding["input_ids"][i][j])
        confidence = confidence_scores[i][j]
        print(f"Label: {label} | Confidence: {confidence:.2f} | Text: {text}")

Note the use of id2label, a dictionary where the key is the id and the value is the corresponding label. This allows for the parsing of the tag.

can you help me with this Error please:
ValueError: You must provide as many words as there are bounding boxes

It looks like the error ValueError: You must provide as many words as there are bounding boxes indicates a mismatch between the number of words and the bounding boxes you've supplied to the LayoutLMv3 model. I need more details to help you

can i share with you my project ?

well, I don't know how I'd do it, but feel free to share.
